# Empty banner on election page for future elections

Tags: bug, status-review, design, election

When viewing the election page of an [election which hasn't started yet](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/election/5), there's an empty blue banner at the bottom:

[image]

It should either be hidden, or filled with something like

> Nominations will start in *x* days.

because that is what is says for a [live election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/):

[image: live election page with banner showing "Nominations close in 6 days."]

Comment: I think that box is also where the election stats (e.g. numbers of eligible voters, who visited the site/page during the election, and who voted – and the results – once it's done) would be shown for a concluded election (e.g. [the 2015 Cryptography mod election](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/election/1)).